# pyodbc ImportError in virtualenv on MacOSX

Tags: python, importerror, pyodbc

In my virtualenv, where I have pyodbc installed, when trying to import pyodbc in python it returns this error.

```
ImportError: 
dlopen(/Users/junruchen/.python-eggs/pyodbc-3.0.7-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg-tmp/pyodbc.so, 2):
Symbol not found: _GetPrivateProfileString
  Referenced from: /usr/lib/libiodbc.2.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

I have no idea what's going on, I checked site-packages in the venv/lib/python2.7 and the pyodbc files are there. Can anyone direct me to the right path?

I have downloaded iODBC and installed it on the system

then I installed pyodbc by downloading the source and running:

```
$python setup.py build
$python setup.py install
```

I did this both within and outside of the virtualenv and neither seems to be working. Both are giving me the same error.

when I open iodbctest I get:

```
iODBC Demonstration program    
This program shows an interactive SQL processor
Driver Manager: 03.52.0709.0909

Enter ODBC connect string (? shows list): ?

DSN                              | Driver                                  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Enter ODBC connect string (? shows list):
```

does this mean that I haven't done the configuration properly?

Comment: What is/was your virtualenv directory? Because `/Users/junruchen/.python-eggs` is a really weird path to find Python modules on, if you simply ran `python setup.py install`.

Comment: that's what I thought too, but my virtualenv is setup like this: /Users/junruchen/[folder]/flask/venv @Evert

Comment: but in my   /Users/junruchen/[folder]/flask/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages I see /pyodbc-3.0.7-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg

Comment: Check your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, and change it as necessary (remove that `.python-eggs` directory. Alternatively, just (re)move/rename the `.python-eggs` directory, so that it can't be found by Python. That should avoid this one and pick up the other one in site-packages. Possibly, you still get the same error, but at least you won't have possible conflicting Python package directories.

Comment: Also, how did you install iODBC? I came across [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905093/iodbc-does-not-work-under-mac-osx-10-6-4), which looks like it's the same. The suggestion that you need a different iODBC installation may work.